# How to set a default empty binding unless the value is different from 0?

Tags: wpf

When I initially set up a binding `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}"..>` the UI gives 0 as the int defaults to 0. First, how to stop showing the result unless the Position is not `0` ? Second, if the `Position = 5`, the UI shows the result, if it goes to `0` again, stop showing the result again

Comment: What if Position set explicitly to 0?

Comment: Whats with all the double negatives? Can't you just ask how to set it to empty when 0?

Comment: @baozi - Use `IValueConverter` and put the check in there. If value is 0 return string.Empty else return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, int is a value type, meaning that it can never be `null`. You can use the `Nullable<int>` to transform it as a Nullable, that defaults to `null`.

A shortcut is with the question mark.
If you define your Position as `int? Position` you should get the result you're after.

**Edit:** 
Didn't see the request about the value disappearing after the `Position = 0` again.

A good alternative would be to use a IValueConverter as proposed in the comments.

Otherwise, you could use a trigger, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock"
       Text="{Binding Position}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringFormat in your binding

```
Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#}'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text box is part of a DataTemplate, use a DataTrigger to set the TextBlock's Text to an empty string

```
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Position}"
                     Value="0">
            <Setter TargetName="textPosition"
                    Property="Text"
                    Value="" />
        </DataTrigger>
```

Otherwise, you can use a Converter on the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"..>
```

Converter:

```
public class ValConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        return value;
    }



    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```